# Why is my Observable never Resolved?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I am a newbie in javascript and I was going through Angular 2 Documentation and just happen to see that you can replace Promises with Observable. I have a very simple code and I don't know why i am getting other two extra result here. I do get the value that I wanted, However I also get some ZoneAwarePromise and Observable. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const getIDs = new Observable((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next([254, 568, 874, 258]);
        observer.next([1245, 458]);
    }, 100);
});


getIDs.subscribe((IDs) => {
  console.log(IDs);
});

async function testing() {
  const result = await getIDs;
  console.log(result);
  console.log('Print First');
}

const x = testing();
console.log(x);
```

Console output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Async/await will not work for Observable. You have to subscribe inside test function.

```
async function testing() {
  getIDs.subscribe((IDs) => {
    console.log(IDs);
    console.log('Print First');
  });
  //const result = await getIDs;
  // console.log(result);

}
```